# Are there any databases that focus on query and read performance?

Tags: database

Are there any databases that focus more on insanely fast read/querying performance? I am looking for a good nosql document database that I don't plan for any significance writes (updating the database is only done by me on a weekly schedule). The type of query I will be doing are keyword searches that will search multiple string fields and interval searching that will look for elements within/overlap an interval.

I was looking at Redis initially, but I needed something a bit more extensive than key/value to store my data. MongoDB looks like a good choice?

Comment: Can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198960/practical-example-for-each-type-of-database-real-cases/18301125#18301125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible solutions for your problem, the right solution depends mostly on the scale and the actual use case.
Redis does quite a bit more than simple key/value storage, but I doubt that it's what you need right now.

For mostly read only storage and these type of searches I would recommend taking a look at Elasticsearch and/or Solr, should do what you need and more.

Basically... fast to read, slow to write means lots of denormalisation. You can do that yourself, you can (with some apps) let the database take care of it. But it's always a trade off.