# how to manage user sessions in distributed databases?

Tags: postgresql, session, database-design, database-replication

Since i have zero experience in developing web applications which can be scaled up horizontally, i need someone with experience guide me in right direction.

I had difficulties to figure out the right way of storing login sessions in database, so i came to the question is that even right to store them in databases when i am planing to use replication in future ? and if not what are the alternates ??

I need different clients(android,Windows, ...) be connected to server with their own sessions related to the same user and i am using:

1 - Cent-OS as OS

2 - PostgreSQL as DBMS

3 - Tomee as HTTP server and Servlet container

4 - Partitioned Tables (Inherited Tables in PostgreSQL) to improve performance, chance of in memory index scan, prevent fragmentation and etc

My problem raise from the fact that i need to check session availability in every received request from clients (every session has its own encryption keys) and it is possible to have millions of sessions, in a distributed environment i can not be sure that the created session will be available in replicated database at the right time.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the user sessions in RDBMS will evantually decrease the perfermance of your application. You should take a look at distributed caching mechanisms to store and read user sessions. I strongly recommend NoSQL database solutions for user sessions such as Redis which enables you in-memory storage of your key-value pairs and responds in a very high speed. In addition, you can tune the configuration file in order to store the in-memory key-value pairs to disk for persistence. You also need to focus on distribution of your key-value pairs across multiple NoSQL instances and internal data structures such as HashMaps. You can use your own hashing algorithm to distribute your key-value pairs on multiple instances that will enable you high availability. You should keep in mind that shardening your data horizontally will result in some issues, you can refer to [CAP theorem - Availability and Partition Tolerance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346326/cap-theorem-availability-and-partition-tolerance) fore details.